# How to Update Label From Different View Controller using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, label, nsuserdefaults, ibaction

I am trying to update a label on view controller 1 by pressing a button on different view controller 2. I have this IBAction in the view controller 2:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    DropPinVC * vc = [[DropPinVC alloc]init];

    NSString *updatedLabel = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Type Location"];

    NSLog(@"Updated Label = %@", updatedLabel);

    vc.TypeLabel.text = updatedLabel;

    [self closeScreen];
}
```

However, the label on view controller 1 does not update. Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**vc** is a new instance of **DropPinVC** class declared in the scope of the action posted, and is not the same instance as the one you want to update.

One way to achieve this is to keep a pointer to the first view controller.

In order for **viewController2(vc2)** to update a **UILabel** that is owned by **viewController1(vc1)**, **vc2** needs a reference to **vc1** so it can access the label.

Add a property to **vc2** of type **DropPinVC**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) DropPinVC *vc1Ref;
```

Assuming **vc1** allocates and initialises **vc2** then where after this happens assign the **vc1Ref** property.

```
vc2.vc1Ref = self;
```

Now in the IBAction, your code can now access the correct instance and update the correct label.

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

NSString *updatedLabel = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Type Location"];

NSLog(@"Updated Label = %@", updatedLabel);

self.vc1Ref.TypeLabel.text = updatedLabel;

[self closeScreen];
}
```